# FadeTransition() widget is animated only once in flutter?

Tags: animation, flutter

```
class pin extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_PinState createState() => _PinState();
}

class _PinState extends State<pin> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
AnimationController _controller;
Animation<double> _animation;
bool error = false;


@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  this._controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), vsync: this);
  this._animation =
      Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controller,
    curve: Curves.easeIn,
  ));
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if(this.error) {
    this.error = false;
    _controller.forward();
  }
  return Container(
    child: if (this.error)
            Container(
            child: FadeTransition(
              opacity: _animation,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Image.asset("assets/images/sad_face.png"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),    
  ),
}
}
```

In the above code `FadeTransition()` widget is animated when the app is first launched. 
and the visibility of `FadeTransition()` is toggled by the `error` variable.
but when next time the `FadeTransition()` widget is visible it is not animated?

what is missing, when toggling `FadeTransition()` the widget should be animated every time it appears!

the `error` variable is set from outside using `Providers` and wherever the `error` is changed the widget is rebuilt, so no need to use `setState()`

Answer (score 11):

One thing I noticed is `error` is always false. There is no code to turn it to true and there are two places where it would be set to false. One of them dependent on if it is true (which it will never be since `error = true` doesn't exist)

That being said, if you want to make your animation run again, where ever you are toggling this property (usually in a button's `onTap` method) you have to call setState.
In the setState you can either use

```
controller.forward(from: 0);
// or
controller.reset(); // stops the animation if in progress
controller.forward();
```

Comment: the problem is solved when using `controller.forward(from: 0);` but I wonder other animation works fine without using `from` in `controller`, why?